# 98 Park Avenue Windows won't work

Tags: power-windows, buick, park-avenue

1998 Buick Park Avenue: none of the windows work, except the front driver side.  None of the driver controls work to control them either.  Checked all fuses which are OK.

Comment: On my Accord, even the driver's controls don't work if the window lock is on.  Not to insult you, but be sure the lock is off first.

Comment: How is the battery?

Comment: @Keith - I believe it works the same on GM vehicles as well (at least it does on the ones I've driven with a lock out feature).

Answer (score 1):

If you have electric controls, then it's possible that the little metal clips inside the switches have broken off or bent enough to no longer make contact. I have to rebuild the passenger switch in my 01 Dodge Ram 1500 every now and then for the same reason.

If none of the controls work on any of the windows, then it could be a severed or disconnected wire or a short in the wiring (Even though fuses are ok). Fuses may have been replaced with higher amp fuses to prevent blowing which means your switches or wiring have probably been burned up by a short.

A lot of possibilities so I recommend pulling out a switch panel and examining the internals.